# glxinfo returns Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig on wsl2 - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opengl

I know that there are already similar to posts to this, but none have worked for me. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on wsl2 and using Xming as the graphical backend. Commands such as `xeyes` work fine, `nvidia-smi` works fine, but whenever I run `glxinfo` I get this error:

[image: Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig]

```
(base) user@user-PC:~$ glxinfo
name of display: 127.0.0.1 (some other ip was shwon here)
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

I am running a 3060 with up-to-date drivers. I have tried reinstall mesa-utils and `glxgears` gives a similiar error. If you need any more info let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.